# Logwatch Not Sending Emails

Tags: email, logwatch

I am on Ubuntu 20.04 server and I have installed / configured logwatch according these Ubuntu instructions that are little outdated:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Logwatch

While I can execute `logwatch` in terminal...  and see output... I cannot get it to send email.

I tried both:

`mailer = "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t"`  and `mailer = "/usr/bin/mailx -mgt"`

With no success..

Any tips?

Comment: Can your server send email at all?

Comment: Yes... I  am getting regular webmin, cron, AIDE, emails no problem...   logwatch doesn't even show up in the logs

Comment: Then take a look at this https://askubuntu.com/a/829650/243321

Comment: I saw that... I just tried it.... no luck... after I manually run the cron... I check `/var/log/mail.log` and there is no record that logwatch at all...  it is if the entire mailer option is just ignored.